# Linq group by performance

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of post objects. Each post object has a car property and each car object has a brand property. I am trying to find total number of posts for a particular brand, for this I am using the following code

```
var grp = posts.Where(t=> !t.Car.Brand.Name.Equals("Test"))
                .Select(t=> new Brand
                {
                    BrandId = t.Car.Brand.Id,
                    Name = t.Car.Brand.Name,
                    Url = t.Car.Brand.Url,
                })
                .GroupBy(t => t.BrandId)
                .Select(t=> new Brand
                {
                    BrandId = t.First().BrandId,
                    Name = t.First().Name,
                    Url = t.First().Url,
                    Count = t.Count()
                }).OrderByDescending(t=>t.Count).ToList();
```

This code works but it is a bit slow, any suggestions to improve performance?

Comment: Could you post the generated SQL? also could you try calling `BrandId = t.BrandId; Name = t.Max(s => s.Name); Url = t.Max(s => s.Url)` and seeing if that helps? `t.First()` may do some in memory things, but i'm not sure. 

Also post your ef core version, and what do you consider 'slow'?

Comment: Maybe do it in two steps. Execute with .ToList() then group: .GroupBy(t => t.BrandId).Where(w => w.Count() > 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `First()` on grouping result dramaticallly decrease perfromance. Up to EF Core 6 it will thtow exception that this query is not translatablke. If you want to write performant queries always think in SQL way: grouping can return only grouping keys and aggregation result, other quirks are slow, even they are translatable to the SQL.

```cs
var grp = posts
    .Where(t => !t.Car.Brand.Name.Equals("Test"))
    .Select(t => new Brand
    {
        BrandId = t.Car.Brand.Id,
        Name = t.Car.Brand.Name,
        Url = t.Car.Brand.Url,
    })
    .GroupBy(t => t)
    .Select(t => new Brand
    {
        BrandId = t.Key.BrandId,
        Name = t.Key.Name,
        Url = t.Key.Url,
        Count = t.Count()
    })
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Count)
    .ToList();
```